# Cybersecutiry: Springboot actuator env and info show connection string uri mongodb

Tags: mongodb, security, spring-boot-actuator, info

Mongodb driver need connection string by spring.data.mongodb.uri and you can't set it by single properties.

When you call actuator info or env, it show all secrets data for mongodb as username,password, host,...

**Exists a workaround to hide specific properties for info in this case spring.data.mongodb.uri ?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exposing env and info endpoints can be a costly security mistake.

You can either [disable the endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.enabling) if not needed or [turn on authentication and access control for certain endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security).

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use

```
management:
  endpoint:
    info:
      enabled: true
      keys-to-sanitize: # Hide secrets data for cybersecurity
        spring.data.mongodb.uri,.*password*.,.*secret.*,.*key.*,.*token.*,.*credentials.*
    env:
      enabled: true
      keys-to-sanitize: # Hide secrets data for cybersecurity
        spring.data.mongodb.uri,.*password*.,.*secret.*,.*key.*,.*token.*,.*credentials.*
```